# How to find which cells in a column have numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have several name of products in Column A, like this

```
Biscuit
Chocolate
Hibis400
Cratey
Ubbret-131-small
Hingley
```

The data runs into hundreds and thousands. IS there a way to quickly identify which of the cells contains numbers (of any kind, single digits or multiple). I cannot get past it.

Comment: *"I cannot get past it."* You can't get past what? Please share what you're trying and where you've gotten stuck. An example of the results you expect Excel to produce is also helpful.

Comment: Tried ISNUMBER, but its not geving the desired result. And why do u want to know what I tried, why can't you just give your suggestion and let others and myself decide if it works or not.

Comment: With your reputation, you should know that is not how this site works (per [ask]). Remember, we are not a script writing service. Everyone helps for free and it's nice to know there has been some effort made and not just an expectation for us to do it for you. If we know what you've tried, we won't suggest it or maybe we can correct it if there is an error.

Comment: The way I see it, its a 0 or 1 issue. Either one knows it or not. Hence it doesn't matter what I tried, bcoz I really cannot get past it. Now that you know the whole shebang, can you put some inputs, or let others do it.